# Eliminar doble petición de GET con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Genero una petición get con un botón para enviar, pero cuando le doy click en el botón cancelar y le doy click en otro archivo, se duplica. Vale decir, la petición anterior con la nueva, o sea, envió 2 veces distintos formularios.

Lo peor es que si le doy en el botón cancelar y voy a otro archivo ahora hace 3 envíos y así sucesivamente.

Les ajunto unos pantallazos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen de arriba le estoy dando click al primer archivo creo que se nota atrás

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es cuando le doy en con el botón cancelar y le doy en otro archivo en este caso el segundo.

Adjunto código Jquery

```
 function ingresar_codigo() {
$("#codigo").numeric();
limpiar_todo();
var numero;
var name1;
var nombre_comp;
$('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'button#imprimir', function () {
    $('#modal_form_proceso').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false  
    })
    $('#modal_form_proceso').modal('show');
    $(this).closest('button').find("input#nombre_rd").each(function () {
        numero = (this.value);
    });
    $(this).closest('button').find("input#nombre_comp").each(function () {
        nombre_comp = (this.value);
    });
    $.get(baseurl + 'resolucion/print_qr?numero=' + numero + '&' + 'nombre_comp=' + nombre_comp, {
    });
    $("#btnGuardar").click(function () {
        var codigo = $('#codigo').val();
        $.post(baseurl + 'resolucion/codigo_correcto', {codigo: codigo, nombre_comp: nombre_comp, numero: numero}, function (data) {
            var dato = $.trim(data);
            if ($.trim(dato) == '1' || $.trim(dato) == null) {
                $('#mRespuestaImpresion').modal('show');
                $('#msg_respuestaImpresion').text('El codigo ingresado es incorrecto');
                $("#codigo").css("border", "1px solid red");
                $("#codigo").focus();
            } else {
                var win = window.open(baseurl +
                        'resolucion/Archivo?numero=' + numero + '&' + 'codigo=' + codigo,
                        '_blank' 
                        );
                win.focus();
                limpiar_todo();
                $('#modal_form_proceso').modal('hide');
                $('#mRespuesta').modal('show');
                $('#msg_respuesta').text('Espere mientras imprime el documento');
            }
        });
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Una recomendación que te ahorarrá dolores de cabeza: no ejecutes los submits de formularios con eventos de botón, si no mediante el evento `submit` del formulario: `$('#tuform').on('submit', function(e) { ... });`. Tus botones deben tener un rol, y esto se hace mediante el atributo `type`. Si no especificas este atributo en un formulario, por defecto será `type="submit"`. El botón cancelar debería tener `type=button"` y agregar un evento para cerrar la modal. Hacer ésto te asegura que el submit se hará **siempre y cuando** se haya pulsado el botón submit **dentro del formulario**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, cuando haces el primer evento click, se agrega un evento en btnGuardar, si haces otra ves click, se vuelve a agregar el evento al botón, en java script no se sobre-escriben solo se agregan, y eso genera que se hagan varias peticiones, yo para que no me suceda eso utilizo la función [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) que elimina todos los eventos previamente asignados ejemplo (Por ahi y que tengas que aumentar otros unbind, pero ya sabes como va la cosa):

```
function ingresar_codigo() {
    $("#codigo").numeric();
    limpiar_todo();
    var numero;
    var name1;
    var nombre_comp;
    $('#example1 tbody').unbind();
    $('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'button#imprimir', function () {
        $('#modal_form_proceso').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false  
        })
        $('#modal_form_proceso').modal('show');
        $(this).closest('button').find("input#nombre_rd").each(function () {
    numero = (this.value);
        });
        $(this).closest('button').find("input#nombre_comp").each(function () {
            nombre_comp = (this.value);
});
$.get(baseurl + 'resolucion/print_qr?numero=' + numero + '&' + 'nombre_comp=' + nombre_comp, {
});
$("#btnGuardar").unbind();
$("#btnGuardar").click(function () {
    var codigo = $('#codigo').val();
    $.post(baseurl + 'resolucion/codigo_correcto', {codigo: codigo, nombre_comp: nombre_comp, numero: numero}, function (data) {
        var dato = $.trim(data);
        if ($.trim(dato) == '1' || $.trim(dato) == null) {
            $('#mRespuestaImpresion').modal('show');
            $('#msg_respuestaImpresion').text('El codigo ingresado es incorrecto');
            $("#codigo").css("border", "1px solid red");
            $("#codigo").focus();
        } else {
            var win = window.open(baseurl +
                    'resolucion/Archivo?numero=' + numero + '&' + 'codigo=' + codigo,
                    '_blank' 
                    );
            win.focus();
            limpiar_todo();
            $('#modal_form_proceso').modal('hide');
            $('#mRespuesta').modal('show');
            $('#msg_respuesta').text('Espere mientras imprime el documento');
        }
    });
});
   });
   }
```

Suerte!

Comment: Respeto!!! mil gracias

Comment: No se sobreescriben siempre y cuando se añadan los handlers con `addEventListener`, lo que hace que los listeners se añadan a una cola y que sean ejecutados en el orden en el que fueron añadidos. Si se agrega un evento mediante `onclick`, elimina cualquier handler previamente añadido.